# Firebase simultaneous realtime connections to my database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the free plane in Firebase - I have 100 simultaneous realtime connections.
But I didnt understand one thing:
Now, No one connected to my app, and in Firebase - It is written that I have 3 connection. What that mean?
I have 100 connections in general or maximum 100 simultaneous realtime connections?

I would love someone to explain to me how it works.

thanks

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. You have a maximum of 100 simultaneous connections, that's the restriction.

Comment: @PieterLaebens simultaneous connections? Now, no one connect to the database and its written that I have 3 connections. I try to understand what is "simultaneous connections" in firebase?

Comment: I guess an example of a connection is whenever `DatabaseReference.setValue()`is called. Would be nice to know for sure.

Comment: I have the same problem. I am running the application/react just locally and the firebase database usage console shows a big different number. Would be nice if someone know what is happening and how to close all firebase database connection.

Comment: please, is that include reading data from a real-time database? I.e  I have a boolean and I read this value from my android project if that will be applied as 100 Sim. conn? if I have 200 users using the app simultaneously will bring any issues?

Answer (score 15):

The [FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#pricing-simultaneous) has an item that explains what a connection is:

> A simultaneous connection is equivalent to one mobile device, browser tab, or server app connected to the database. Firebase imposes hard limits on the number of simultaneous connections to your app's database. These limits are in place to protect both Firebase and our users from abuse.
>
> The Spark plan limit is 100 and cannot be raised. The Flame and Blaze plans have a limit of 200,000 simultaneous connections per database.
>
> This limit isn't the same as the total number of users of your app, because your users don't all connect at once. If you need more than 200,000 simultaneous connections, please read Scale with Multiple Databases.

Comment: Firebase announce yesterday the new limit of 200 000 simultaneous connections. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/09/increasing-realtime-database-scaling.html

Answer (score 4):

**I know why!**

The 3/100 means **during the time period**, you have **reached 3 connections** as peak value (not real time data!)[image]

Change the time period to **last 60 minutes**, then you can see real time data chart! (and see the **peak** label next to the connection value)

---

FYI, even though this data is now up to date, when you manually change the connection number (by closing tab or other coding stuff), you still need to **wait a little bit time** (30 seconds, one minute? not sure) **before refreshing the chart and see the updated data.**

[image]

Comment: Great. but `100 limit` for request in 1 second or 1 minute or 1 day?

Answer (score 1):

i made an inquiry with Firebase support to understand what the steps to increasing the max simultaneous connection count are, or to at least understand how they determine who is eligible for an increase. granted, 100,000 simultaneous connections is likely a very hard limit to breach, i suspect they are reluctant to do this easily for the simple fact that despite a three email back-and-forth in which i was very clear and direct with my questioning, i never got answers to my questions.

instead, the two recommendations i consistently got were to either:

1. shard your data. per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits) (emphasis mine):

> A simultaneous connection is equivalent to one mobile device, browser
>   tab, or server app connected to the database. This isn't the same as
>   the total number of users of your app, because your users don't all
>   connect at once. For example, apps with 10 million monthly active
>   users usually have fewer than 100,000 simultaneous connections. Your
>   max simultaneous connections depends on your total user count and the
>   average time users spend in your app.
>
> **However, if you need to scale beyond this limit, try using multiple
>   databases**.

2. try *Cloud Firestore* as it will support [automatic scaling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore#scalability) (emphasis mine):

> Scaling will be automatic.
>
> Scales completely automatically (**after
>   beta**), meaning you don't need to shard your data across multiple
>   instances.

Comment: Hi, in our company we are facing the same question - "Is it possible to upgrade the number of sim. conns. ?". I was wondering, since 3 months have passed since your initial inquiry , do you have more information about this question?

Comment: i'm afraid not, sorry

Comment: please, is that include reading data from a real-time database? I.e  I have a boolean and I read this value from my android project if that will be applied as 100 Sim. conn? if I have 200 users using the app simultaneously will bring any issues?

Answer (score 0):

> A simultaneous connection is equivalent to one mobile device, browser
> tab, or server app connected to the database. This isn't the same as
> the total number of users of your app, because your users don't all
> connect at once. For example, apps with 10 million monthly active
> users usually have fewer than 200,000 simultaneous connections. Your
> max simultaneous connections depends on your total user count and the
> average time users spend in your app.

Source : [Firebase Documentation on Realtime Database Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits)

Q : I have 100 connections in general or maximum 100 simultaneous realtime connections?

A : It's 100 simultaneous realtime connections.

Comment: Does it mean, that at the one moment I can have 100 ongoing requests to database? Besause I can see, Firebase uses socket to do stuff, and I have subscription on database data change. Does 1 subscription is taken to count over time or just my requests for data?