# How to close the connection in Firebase (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app name is iDialogue and app concept is “ to get the dialogue list(Dialogue name in the text, m4a file format) from the firebase and show on table view”.

Firebase allows to make 100 connections simultaneously but what about 101’s connection?

Basically, I want this flow:

- Step 1 - When app launch makes connection and download data.
- Step 2 - After that close connection because there is no need of
  connection when the app goes background then also close the
  connection.
- Step 3- App become relaunch or come to foreground then open the
  connection and download the data again close it.

There is no need of real time data updating, please suggest me if there is any possibility for 101'th connection if you have some other idea for it.

so please help me how to implement above flow in Firebase.

Comment: It appears you want to connect to Firebase when the app starts or comes to the foreground, download data and then close the firebase connection? If so, connecting to Firebase and getting data is covered in the [Firebase Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start). If you want the app to do that any time it comes to the foreground, see func applicationWillEnterForeground. I'm marking this as a duplicate as all of the parts already been answered. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597039/firebase-simultaneous-realtime-connections-to-my-database)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase simultaneous realtime connections to my database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597039/firebase-simultaneous-realtime-connections-to-my-database)