# Firebase Realtime Database - Scaling above 100.000 concurrent connections

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, autoscaling

The application I'm currently working on needs real-time communication that is scalable. We have been looking into and tried out Firebase real-time database and firestore. It seems Firebase real-time database is more mature and tested out, while firestore is still in beta, which is why we are leaning towards the real-time database.

We are however worried about its scaling capabilities in our context. Our queries will mainly be geo spatial based on the user's location. According to [Firebase simultaneous realtime connections to my database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597039/firebase-simultaneous-realtime-connections-to-my-database) and https://firebase.google.com/pricing/#faq-simultaneous the maximum number of concurrent users is 100.000, which will be too low for our needs.

According to their documentation, it seems like database sharding is the way to scale beyond 100.000 concurrent users https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding. Since our queries are based on the user's location, we could group the data into regions, e.g. US West, US Central, and US East and have a database instance for each of those three regions.

While this method may work, it seems very cumbersome to set it up. We would probably need to have a service which the user initially connects to in order to be redirected to the correct database instance that fits the region which the user is in. Additionally, it should handle the case where a user moves into another region, and should therefore be redirected to another database instance containing the data for that specific region.
Another complex task would be to distribute the data into the correct database instances.

Is there a more simple approach to scale beyond 100.000 users or is it possible to increase the amount of concurrent connections for a single Firebase real-time database?
To me it seems like almost a waste to use Firebase if it requires you to do so much "load" balancing yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The 100K concurrent connections is a hard cap on the Firebase Realtime Database.

The approach you describe with a two-step connect is quite idiomatic. The first step is usually quite simple. In fact for many apps it is part of  their authentication flow, or based on the outcome of that. For example, many apps base the user's shard on a hash of their UID.

In your case, you could inject the users region into their token as a [custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) when they register. Then you'd get that claim when they sign in, and can redirect them to their shard. You could also persist the shard info in the client when they first connect, so that you only have to determine that only once for each client/device.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more simple approach to scale beyond 100.000 users or is it
>   possible to increase the amount of concurrent connections for a single
>   Firebase real-time database?

Yes. use Firestore database.

Scales completely automatically. Currently, scaling limits are:

- Around **1 million concurrent connections and 10,000 writes/second.** (they plan to increase these limits in the future) ([source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore))
- **Maximum write rate** to a document is 1 per second ([source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas))

Is officially out of beta and in General Availability from 31/1/2019 ([source](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/01/cloud-firestore-in-general-availability.html))

Comment: there are things that firestore sucks at.the pricing model is shitty. you can't use it for IOT devices. can't make real time games else it would cost you way more than RTDB. so just scaling is not issue always. but the use case as well. while RTDB is handy in such use cases where there is frequent data flow. but it cost way more to store data in it.