# is there a limit for requests which firebase server can send/recieve at the same time?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If there are many users are using the app and get/set values from/to firebase at the same moment, is it guaranteed that it will be successful operation? or are there any cases should be handled to avoid missing data ?

will debugging I used `setValue()` to push about 1800 message to firebase db, it can't write all of them , some data was missed and not all of 1800 was written successfully, I tried `sleep()` about 100ms in the loop,it write all of them successfully, So I wondered if there 1800 user at the same time can the server handle their requests

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase simultaneous realtime connections to my database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597039/firebase-simultaneous-realtime-connections-to-my-database)

Comment: thank you, But I think it's different one

Comment: Did you check for errors in the code that makes the writes?  Did you log it?

Comment: No it didn't, but when I tried ```sleep()``` the srever accepted all messages

Comment: I would suggest looking at Firebase Transactions as a solution to guarantee data integrity. However, what @DougStevenson said is on point - it's more like a coding issue on the client than the server failing to write the data.

Comment: ok, thank you, but anyway is there a limit for the server requests at the same time?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking; what is a *server request*? A query? A write? Triggering a cloud function? Most if that is pretty well covered in the Firebase Documentation [Realtime Database Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits). Again though the server can candle 64MB/minute and a single write operation up to 256MB so exceeding that would be an issue. Oh, when responding to another user, you can notify them of your response by using the 'at' symbol with their name, like this @Jay. My guess is your have a coding issue otherwise.

Comment: @Jay thank you, the mentioned doc answered my question, I think the count of messages I sent per second was more than 10MB, so when I used  ```sleep()``` it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jay, the mentioned doc answered my question, I think the size of messages I sent per second was more than 10MB, so when I used sleep() it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is probably guaranteed for your use case. When you will have more than one million users, maybe you should reconsider the question ;)

For instance at the time of writing this (april 2020) the maximum writes per second among all documents in a Firestore database is 10,000 per second or 10mb and the maximum concurrent connections for mobile/web clients per database is 1,000,000

You can see all this things here: [firestore quotas](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas)

Comment: thank you, will debugging I used ```setValue()``` to push about 1800 message to firebase db, it can't write all of them , some data was missed and not all of 1800 was written successfully, So I wondered if there 1800 user at the same time can the server handle their requests

Comment: You provided a link for Firestore, but I think the question is about Realtime Database.